# JQuery UI dialog : TypeError: a(...).parents(...).andSelf is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, typeerror

I'm new to jquery and I wanted to add a dialog to my page when a function is called.
Whenever I call this function from the console, the dialog shows up but with the error below.
What did it mean and how to solve it ?

```js
Uncaught TypeError: a(...).parents(...).andSelf is not a function
    at d (jquery-ui.min.js:5)
    at c (jquery-ui.min.js:5)
    at Array.tabbable (jquery-ui.min.js:5)
    at jquery.min.js:2
    at r (jquery.min.js:2)
    at se.select (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.se [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at a.<computed>.<computed>.open (jquery-ui.min.js:5)
    at a.<computed>.<computed>._init (jquery-ui.min.js:5)
```

I'v used these jquery libraries :

```html
<script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script> //Given with my bootstrap theme
<script src="../vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And the function I called is this one :

```js
function afficherPopupErreur() {
    $('body').append('<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"><p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the x icon.</p></div>');
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
}
```

I know that this append is quite weird but it was just to try the dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[andSelf](https://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) is deprecated and removed - use newer JQUI

Also always use the HTTPS versions

```js
function afficherPopupErreur() {
  $('body').append('<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"><p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the x icon.</p></div>');
  $("#dialog").dialog();
}

$(function() {
  afficherPopupErreur();
});
```

```css
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close { float:right}
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close::after { content:"X" }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-bootstrap/0.5pre/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 12):

`.andSelf()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 3.0.

`.addBack()` should be used instead from jQuery 1.8 onward.

Try to replace "andSelf" with "addBack" in your code